# updating rows instead of creating new entries database android

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, row

I have been working on recipe from Android recipe book to utilize a database for storing events. Current code allows me to add new entries but I am unable to modify any of the added entries. What I need is a database with predefined number of rows(48) with functionality of updating these rows through corresponding edittext fields. Can anyone help me to modify the following code to achieve this please? I am new to android coding and I need to start with this database.

Here is my MyDB file:

```
package com.cookbook.data;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyDB {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;
    private final MyDBhelper dbhelper;
    // Initializes MyDBHelper instance
    public MyDB(Context c){
        context = c;
        dbhelper = new MyDBhelper(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                                            Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    // Closes the database connection
    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }
    // Initializes a SQLiteDatabase instance using MyDBhelper
    public void open() throws SQLiteException
    {
        try {
            db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Open database exception caught", ex.getMessage());
            db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
    }
    // Saves a diary entry to the database as name-value pairs in ContentValues instance
    // then passes the data to the SQLitedatabase instance to do an insert
    public long insertdiary(String title, String content)
    {
        try{
            ContentValues newTaskValue = new ContentValues();
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME,  title);
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.CONTENT_NAME, content);
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.DATE_NAME,     java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());            
            return db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME,  null, newTaskValue);
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Insert into database exception caught",
                    ex.getMessage());
            return -1;
        }
    }


    // Reads the diary entries from database, saves them in a Cursor class and returns     it from the method
    public Cursor getdiaries()
    {
        Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, null,
                            null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }

}
```

Here is my MyDBhelper file:

```
package com.cookbook.data;


import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyDBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    private static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table "+
    Constants.TABLE_NAME+" ("+
    Constants.KEY_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+
    Constants.TITLE_NAME+" text not null, "+
    Constants.CONTENT_NAME+" text not null, "+
    Constants.DATE_NAME+" long);";
    // database initialization
    public MyDBhelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                        int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.v("MyDBhelper onCreate","Creating all the tables");
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Create table exception", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                            int newVersion) {
        Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version "+oldVersion
                                +" to "+newVersion
                                +", which will destroy all     old data");
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+Constants.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }




}
```

Here is my Constants file:

```
package com.cookbook.data;

public class Constants {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="datastorage";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="diaries";
    public static final String TITLE_NAME="title";
    public static final String CONTENT_NAME="content";
    public static final String DATE_NAME="recorddate";
    public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
    public static final String TABLE_ROW="row_id";
}
```

Here is my Diary file that creates new entries into a database:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;
import com.cookbook.data.MyDBhelper;
public class Diary extends Activity {
    EditText titleET1,contentET1;
    EditText titleET2,contentET2;
    Button submitBT;
    MyDB dba;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.diary);
        dba = new MyDB(this);
        dba.open();
        titleET1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary1);
        contentET1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diarycontentText1);
        titleET2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diary2);
        contentET2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diarycontentText2);
        submitBT = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitBT.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    saveItToDB();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        });
    }



    public void saveItToDB() {
        dba.insertdiary(titleET1.getText().toString(),     contentET1.getText().toString());
        dba.insertdiary(titleET2.getText().toString(),     contentET2.getText().toString());
        dba.close();
        titleET1.setText("");
        contentET1.setText("");
        titleET2.setText("");
        contentET2.setText("");
        Intent i = new Intent(Diary.this, DisplayDiaries.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the Back button */
    public void visitMonday(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Monday.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And finally here is my DisplayDiaries file which returns created diaries in a listview:

```
package com.example.classorganizer;


import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cookbook.data.Constants;
import com.cookbook.data.MyDB;




public class DisplayDiaries extends ListActivity {
    MyDB dba;
    DiaryAdapter myAdapter;
    private class MyDiary{
        public MyDiary(String t, String c, String r){
            title=t;
            content=c;
            recorddate=r;

        }
        public String title;
        public String content;
        public String recorddate;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dba = new MyDB(this);
        dba.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.diaries);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myAdapter = new DiaryAdapter(this);
        this.setListAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    private class DiaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ArrayList<MyDiary> diaries;
        public DiaryAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            diaries = new ArrayList<MyDiary>();
            getdata();
        }

        public void getdata(){
            Cursor c = dba.getdiaries();
            startManagingCursor(c);
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    String title =
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE_NAME));
                    String content =
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Constants.CONTENT_NAME));
                    DateFormat dateFormat =
                            DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
                    String datedata = dateFormat.format(new
                            Date(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(
                                    Constants.DATE_NAME))).getTime());
                    MyDiary temp = new MyDiary(title,content,datedata);
                    diaries.add(temp);
                } while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {return diaries.size();}
        public MyDiary getItem(int i) {return diaries.get(i);}
        public long getItemId(int i) {return i;}
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            View v = arg1;
            if ((v == null) || (v.getTag() == null)) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.diaryrow, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.mTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.mDate = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.datetext);

                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.mdiary = getItem(arg0);
            holder.mTitle.setText(holder.mdiary.title);
            holder.mDate.setText(holder.mdiary.recorddate);

            v.setTag(holder);

            return v;
        }

        public class ViewHolder {
            MyDiary mdiary;
            TextView mTitle;
            TextView mDate;

        }

    }
    /** Called when the user clicks the Back button */
    public void visitDiary(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Diary.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

As I mentioned before, this code when run allows creation new diaries and puts them in a listview. What I need is modify this code so the database has the predefined 48 rows (with default empty content) and diary file allows to modify rows through corresponding 48 edittext fields. Any help with the above will be very much appreciated. I look forward to learning from you. Cheers, Patrick

edit--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Since I am an absolute beginner I am still having problem with creating default 48 rows in my table and then writing code for updating each row with corresponding edittext. Maybe there is some helpful soul that could figure this out for me?

edit 2 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I have updated my MyDBhelper onCreate method with your code like this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.v("MyDBhelper onCreate","Creating all the tables");

        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Constants.KEY_ID, 1);
        cv.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME,  "My App");
        db.insert( Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        String Updatetable= "update" + Constants.TABLE_NAME + 
                "Set" + Constants.CONTENT_NAME + " = " + 1 + 
                "Where" +Constants.KEY_ID +" = " + R.id.diary1;

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Create table exception", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

but upon Diary's onCreate a new row is created instead of updating the existing rows... What am I doing wrong here? I believe that I put the code in the wrong place or I missed something else...

Comment: There were insert statements but where do you wrote updates to update the rows? Also you wrote 48 edit text fields where did you declare those?

Comment: That's the whole point. I am incapable of writing update statements instead of these insert ones. And when it comes to 48 edit text fields I didn't declare all those yet since I don't know how to code first part...

Comment: ok then tell me few things... how are you inserting 48 records and on reference to which field you want to update?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but as far as I am concerned there will be 48 EditText that will allow update of existing rows instead of two that are inserting new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this loop statement:

```
for(int i=1; i <= 48; i++) { insertdiary("", ""); }
```

in my MyDBhelper file in onCreate() method as this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.v("MyDBhelper onCreate","Creating all the tables");



    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);


        for(int i=1; i <= 48; i++) { insertdiary("", ""); } 
    }

    catch(SQLiteException ex) {
        Log.v("Create table exception", ex.getMessage());

    }

}
```

For no avail new rows are not being created. Is it due to the fact that database is already created and this code is not running upon app restart? If so, what can I do to delete database and run this code again?

EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I found the solution:
Changing the method signature to take a SQLiteDatabase as a parameter worked.

```
public long insertdiary(SQLiteDatabase db, String title, String content)
```

together with:

```
for(int i=1; i <= 48; i++) { insertdiary(db, "free",""); }
```

placed within onCreate() method in MyDBhelper file

Problem of creating rows upon database creation solved. Now I need to find a way to populate edittext's with data from newly created rows to give a user a chance to save or change data.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that at this point new 48 rows are created three times in a row each time I hit update button in my Diary file.

Comment: *4 times. loop runs four times. which is 4x 48 newly created rows each time rows are updated.

Comment: When this restriction can be lifted?

Answer (score 1):

This could be an example on how to update a row in your db:

```
 public boolean updateDiaryEntry(String title,String content, long date, long rowId){
        ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
        newValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, title);
        newValue.put(Constants.CONTENT_NAME, content);
        newValue.put(Constants.DATE_NAME, date);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=" + rowId, null)>0;

    }
```

You should put this code in your MyDB file and use it whenever you need to update the values of a specific raw in your db.

Comment: any idea how I could first create default rows that are to be updated later on?

Comment: I tried your solution in MyDB but eclipse returns that mDb in last line of your code cannot be resolved.

Comment: but... I don't know what should I do next after using your code. I believe that the records won't start being saved into existing rows just like that....

Comment: what if the first time you create your db you have a for loop where you use your insertDiary method to insert 48 empty raws in your db.And then you can use updateDiaryEntry to update each raw accordingly.

Comment: I will try this and let you know how it goes. Thanks Nahtim

Comment: I inserted this code into MyDB file at the beginning of MyDB class. It doesn't return any errors now. But what should I do next in order to use this method? How do I call it from Diaries file?

Comment: can you give me a hint how to setup the for loop statement please? It sounds reasonable but I don't know where to start with it.

Comment: Ok nahim, placing your code in MyDB and calling this method from within Diaries file works perfect. My new diary entries are placed in the existing rows instead of the new ones. Now I just need to figure out how to construct for loop statement to precreate those domain 48 rows....

Comment: for(int i=1, i<=48,i++) { insertdiary("No Entry", "NoEntry"); }

Comment: Instead of "No entry" you can use whatever message you want or leave it empty String ("")

Comment: I run into some problems with creating rows upon first db creation. Where exactly should I put this code nahtim?

Comment: It seems that the for statement to create 48 rows runs in loop and too many rows are created. How to workaround so only 48 rows are created?

Comment: You should create the 48 rows after the first create of the database.So you should put it in onCreate() of MyDBhelper after the db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

Comment: What you mean too many rows are created? How many?The for loop runs 48 times and inserts an empty row each time.

Comment: when I inserted this code into MyDB file, I cannot remember into which method now, it created waaaay too many rows and continued to create new rows upon each app restart. do I need to clause it in a separate method?

Comment: For me the for loop runs multiple times instead of just one upon database creation but I don't know where to put this code in order to fix this error.

Comment: You have put the for loop in open(), so every time you open the db you create 48 rows. You have to put this code in your myDBhelper file in the onCreate() method like this: `@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.v("MyDBhelper onCreate","Creating all the tables");
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);for(int i=1, i<=48,i++) { insertdiary("", ""); }
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Create table exception", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }`

Comment: It worked once, and when I updated table to new version to drop all data rows are not being created anew...

Comment: Also insertdiary says that is undefined method. I need to change it to MyDB.insertdiary, then change in MyDB insertdiary method to static and db to static as well. Is this healthy way of doing here? loop does not kickstart anyway

Comment: I put this code as you said in onCreate() in DBhelper but loop doesn't create any rows now. I am hopeless..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how do you manuplate the 48 edit text but below example will give you an idea of writing the update query.

```
String Updatetable= "update " + Constants.TABLE_NAME  + "Set " + Constants.CONTENT_NAME + " = " + your value + "Where " +Constants.KEY_ID +" = " + <<May be your edit text value>> +
```

write the above query where you want to update the values

Edit--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

First thing you need to have data on what should those rows contain, Then you have multiple ways to insert data into data.

1. Using Content Values

   `ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
   cv.put(Constants.KEY_ID, 1);
   cv.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, "My App");
   db.insert( Constants.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);`
2. Write a query as above (`Update Query`) and use any of the methods `rawquery`, `execsql`

   `db.rawQuery(<<your insert query>>,null)`

in the same way `execsql` aswell

To get more info check android documention avaialable. [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Comment: ok, but how would I create first 48 rows before updating them?

Comment: Create the those in `onCreate` immediately after you create the table and then in your application just update those rows

Comment: It may sound very dumb I know but how should I declare these rows?

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it seems to be too much sophicated for me. I am an absolute beginner and don't know what to do with the code from my recipe...

Comment: in example 1. what do I need to put in <<data>> ?

Comment: Here Column1 is the column of the table.. for e.g: if column is `_id and it is primary key` then column 1 should be given as a some unique value and coulumn 2 should be value of the second column. check my edited example

Comment: I used your code in MyDBhelper but rows are still being created anew instead of updating the existing ones. I believe I am very wrong somewhere here...

Comment: I am unsure what your code is but one thing is rows will be created when you fire `insert` command and rows will be updated when you fire `update` command, So when you have completed inserted 48 rows don't fire any insert command only use update command

Comment: and for achieving this only substitution of command is sufficient enough?

Comment: can you post where and how are you inserting the data and how are you updating the data?

Comment: As for inserting the data I use Diary file that I posted before. It works with xml file where edittext fields are. I am not sure whether Diary file does it on its own or is just a template for utilizing MyDBhelper file. 
And for updating data, I didn't come so far yet so the data is not being updated so far...