# for loop statement to create rows in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops, rows

I am trying to use for loop statement as follows:

```
for(int i=1; i <= 48; i++) { insertdiary("", ""); }
```

in my MyDB file:

```
package com.cookbook.data;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyDB {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private final Context context;
    private final MyDBhelper dbhelper;



    // Initializes MyDBHelper instance
    public MyDB(Context c){

        context = c;
        dbhelper = new MyDBhelper(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                                            Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    // Closes the database connection
    public void close()
    {
        db.close();
    }

    // Initializes a SQLiteDatabase instance using MyDBhelper
    public void open() throws SQLiteException
    {

        try {
            db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Open database exception caught", ex.getMessage());
            db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
        }
    }


    // Saves a diary entry to the database as name-value pairs in ContentValues instance
    // then passes the data to the SQLitedatabase instance to do an insert
    public long insertdiary(String title, String content)
    {

        try{
            ContentValues newTaskValue = new ContentValues();
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME,  title);
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.CONTENT_NAME, content);
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.DATE_NAME,     java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());            
            return db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME,  null, newTaskValue);
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Insert into database exception caught",
                    ex.getMessage());
            return -1;
        }

    }

    // updates a diary entry (existing row)
        public boolean updateDiaryEntry(String title, long rowId)
        {

            ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
            newValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, title);

            return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=" +     rowId, null)>0;

        }

    // Reads the diary entries from database, saves them in a Cursor class and returns     it from the method
    public Cursor getdiaries()
    {
        Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, null,
                            null, null, null, null);
        return c;
    }

}
```

My aim is to create 48 empty rows upon database or table first creation so I can further update these rows instead of creating new entries. Unfortunately my attempts to utilize this code were unfortunate giving me errors or creating many more rows than 48. 
Is there anyone who could help me with utilizing this code to create 48 rows upon database or table first time creation please?
I appreciate all help.
Paddy

Comment: *"My aim is to create 48 empty rows upon database or table first creation so I can further update these rows instead of creating new entries."* This is invariably a bad idea when you're using a database. Just insert rows when their data is ready.

Comment: The issue with creating 'unused rows' is that you need code **everywhere** to check whether the 'row' is unused! The cost of creating a row when needed against the cost of all the 'checking' code just ain't worth it! i.e. if you get a row then you can be certain it contains useful data!

Comment: What about creating 48 rows with no content or some content but allowing to update them instead of creating the new rows? The problem on my side is that I need to have edittext fields assigned to corresponding rows and I will identify rows by their id.s

Comment: Ryan Vincent. For me the importance is that the empty row is assigned to certain edittext field and represents a block of time in timetable.

Comment: Yes, i appreciate the issue. You want a block of time to be reserved. No problem, have a table that records timeslots and their status (master). Drive off that to the 'detail table' to find the 'actual' 'time slot' use when required.

Comment: can you explain your answer in code Ryan Vincent please?

Comment: You do not need to create lots of empty rows, as my code demonstrates. It is very wasteful of space to do this, as most of them will be empty. You only record the information that you want to show. The code is there. The SQLFiddle is there. I enjoyed doing it.

Comment: @RyanVincent as I said before, it's all sorted now. I have my 48 rows created upon each database creation and I also have 48 edittext's assigned to corresponding rows. My problem now is that I cannot push data from rows into edittext as a suggestion. I can't simply use android:text because there needs to be some code involved.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: from one problem to another trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is really some strict rule governing the requirement to create 48 empty rows, creating them is really the absolute wrong way to go about doing it. Create them as needed, when you need to plug data into them.

Comment: I need to have 48 rows that are corresponding to edittext fields to update the rows as in a diary. Each row represents certain time during the day. I cannot create new rows when needed because they will be sorted from the oldest to the newest which is not expected...

Comment: If not creating 48 'empty' rows, then is there another workaround to link edittext with certain row?

Comment: So wait, you have a diary application and that application has a time table with predefined time blocks. The text is stored in a separate table, linked to the time blocks table and you want to create 48 records in the text table, each to correspond with a time entry in the time table? Is that correct?

Comment: A diary application that has a time table with predefined time blocks. Text is stored through insert or update diary edittext field to the corresponding row in the table(predefined 48 row table with initial or no data). Listview puts rows in a list within  my time table so each row corresponds each time block.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in mysql originally. Had trouble creating an SQLFiddle so i created an SQLite version as well.

There is an **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/835ef/1)**. Squeezing all the stuff that follows into 8K, the SQLFiddle limit, was 'interesting' ;-/

The **SQLite** version, which is exactly the same apart from the 'create table' statements, i will make available if required. It will be a download of the database file, that understand, is the same across all machines. I can also provide the creation scripts if required.

**Purpose:**

The idea, i understand, is to display 'appointments' where the day is split into 48, 30 minute periods.

The requirement is to only **record the actual appointments**.

I pictured it as a small number of departments, recording appointments during the day when events will happen. In my example data, people visiting.

Here is the query to show appointments:

```
SELECT * 
FROM department_appointments_view dav
WHERE dav.the_date = '2014-04-11'
 AND  dav.department_id  = 1
 AND  dav.time_slot_id BETWEEN 12 AND 20;
```

Here is the sample output:

```
appointment_id  department_id  department_code  the_date             time_slot_id  start_time  attendee           reason                 duration  
--------------  -------------  ---------------  -------------------  ------------  ----------  -----------------  ---------------------  ----------
             0              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            12  05:30:00                                                      30
             0              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            13  06:00:00                                                      30
             1              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            14  06:30:00    Catherine Tramell  to see you                     30
             0              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            15  07:00:00                                                      30
             2              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            16  07:30:00    Buddy Ackerman     to see them                    30
             0              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            17  08:00:00                                                      30
             0              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            18  08:30:00                                                      30
             3              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            19  09:00:00    Ivan Drago         to visit someone else          30
             0              1  dept_01          2014-04-11 00:00:00            20  09:30:00                                                      30
```

So, the main table, where appointments are entered, is:

```
CREATE TABLE `department_appointments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `the_date` date NOT NULL,
  `time_slot_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attendee` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dept_fk` (`department_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `dept_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `departments` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

This is the **only** table where appointment information is entered.

Sample data:

```
    id  department_id  the_date    time_slot_id  attendee                 reason                 duration  
------  -------------  ----------  ------------  -----------------------  ---------------------  ----------
     1              1  2014-04-11            14  Catherine Tramell        to see you                     30
     2              1  2014-04-11            16  Buddy Ackerman           to see them                    30
     3              1  2014-04-11            19  Ivan Drago               to visit someone else          30
```

We need some supporting tables:

The **departments** table:

```
CREATE TABLE `departments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `department_code` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Sample data:

```
   id  department_code  title                        
------  ---------------  -----------------------------
     1  dept_01          Dept 01 - The Widget Makers  
     2  dept_02          Dept 02 - For Bar Workers
```

The **calendar**: This is just a table with dates in it. My test data was for april.

```
CREATE TABLE `the_calendar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `the_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

Sample data:
    id  the_date             
------  ---------------------
     1  2014-04-01 00:00:00  
     2  2014-04-02 00:00:00  
     3  2014-04-03 00:00:00  
     4  2014-04-04 00:00:00
```

The **read_only_time_slots** table. This has 48 rows in it with start times. This table is **read only** and never updated or copied or anything.

```
CREATE TABLE `read_only_time_slots` (
  `time_slot_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time_slot_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Sample data:

```
time_slot_id  start_time  duration  
------------  ----------  ----------
           1  00:00:00            30
           2  00:30:00            30
           3  01:00:00            30


----------------------
```

You now need some queries to run this lot. Please be aware that we take advantage of the database engine to do **cartesian products** whenever it can. It will generate all the needed rows for us from just the above tables.

Now, to simplify the use of the information, i have used 'views'. Less confusion for me that way.

**The views**

The first is: **time_slot_view**

```
CREATE VIEW `time_slot_view` AS (
SELECT ts.time_slot_id  AS time_slot_id,
       ts.start_time    AS start_time,
       ts.duration      AS duration
FROM read_only_time_slots ts 
ORDER BY ts.time_slot_id ASC)
```

The next is: **department_calendar_view**

This returns empty timeslots for each department, for each day.

```
CREATE VIEW `department_calendar_view` AS (
SELECT
  `d`.`id`              AS `department_id`,
  `d`.`department_code` AS `department_code`,
  `c`.`the_date`        AS `the_date`,
  `tsv`.`time_slot_id`  AS `time_slot_id`,
  `tsv`.`start_time`    AS `start_time`,
  `tsv`.`duration`      AS `duration`
FROM ((`the_calendar` `c`
    JOIN `time_slot_view` `tsv`)
   JOIN `departments` `d`)
ORDER BY `d`.`department_code`,`c`.`the_date`,`tsv`.`time_slot_id`)
```

Finally: there is the view that uses all the above:

The: **department_appointments_view**

This probably could be done as an outer join. I just used two queries and a union.

```
CREATE VIEW `department_appointments_view` AS 
SELECT  da.id                 AS appointment_id,
        dcv.`department_id`   AS department_id, 
        dcv.`department_code` AS department_code, 
    da.`the_date`         AS the_date, 
    da.`time_slot_id`     AS time_slot_id, 
        dcv.start_time        AS start_time,
    da.`attendee`         AS attendee, 
    da.`reason`           AS reason, 
    da.`duration`         AS duration 
FROM 
    `department_appointments` AS da
INNER JOIN department_calendar_view AS dcv
       ON  da.department_id = dcv.department_id
       AND da.the_date = dcv.the_date
       AND da.time_slot_id = dcv.time_slot_id  
UNION   
SELECT 0,
       dcv.department_id,
       dcv.`department_code` , 
       dcv.the_date,
       dcv.time_slot_id,
       dcv.start_time,
       ''    AS attendee,
       ''    AS reason, 
       dcv.`duration`
FROM department_calendar_view AS dcv 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM  `department_appointments` AS da
                  WHERE  da.department_id = dcv.department_id
                   AND   da.the_date = dcv.the_date
                   AND   da.time_slot_id = dcv.time_slot_id)
ORDER BY department_code, the_date, time_slot_id;
```

Comment: Thank you @Ryan Vincent this looks like a whole lot of work you done here. I managed to find the solution in the meantime with another person. We changed two small things, have a look at my edited post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893385/updating-rows-instead-of-creating-new-entries-database-android

Comment: Now I am battling other problem, I cannot make the edittext show data from corresponding row. This would allow user to keep current data or change it to something else.