# How to delete database and create it a new one

Tags: android, database, loops

I am trying to run this code :

```
for(int i=1; i <= 48; i++) { insertdiary("", ""); }
```

upon database creation in `MyDBhelper` file:

```
...
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.v("MyDBhelper onCreate","Creating all the tables");



    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);


        for(int i=1; i <= 48; i++) { insertdiary("", ""); } 
    }

    catch(SQLiteException ex) {
        Log.v("Create table exception", ex.getMessage());

    }

}
...
```

But for some reason loop does not create new rows. I thought that this may be due to the fact that database is already there and code is not initiated. I might be wrong, this could be due to other reason. Anyway, it would be great to know how I could delete and recreate my database. Updating database version doesn't work as it freezes my app.

Edit---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is MyDBhelper file with new code:

```
package com.cookbook.data;





import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyDBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final String CREATE_TABLE="create table "+
Constants.TABLE_NAME+" ("+
Constants.KEY_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+
Constants.TITLE_NAME+" text not null, "+
Constants.CONTENT_NAME+" text not null, "+
Constants.DATE_NAME+" long);";



// database initialization
public MyDBhelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
                    int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);

}

public void drop() {
drop tables diaries;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.v("MyDBhelper onCreate","Creating all the tables");



    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);


        for(int i=1; i <= 48; i++) { insertdiary("", ""); } 
    }

    catch(SQLiteException ex) {
        Log.v("Create table exception", ex.getMessage());

    }

}

// Saves a diary entry to the database as name-value pairs in ContentValues instance
    // then passes the data to the SQLitedatabase instance to do an insert
    public long insertdiary(String title, String content)
    {

        try{
            ContentValues newTaskValue = new ContentValues();
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME,  title);
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.CONTENT_NAME, content);
            newTaskValue.put(Constants.DATE_NAME, java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis());            
            return db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME,  null, newTaskValue);
        } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.v("Insert into database exception caught",
                    ex.getMessage());
            return -1;
        }

    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
                        int newVersion) {
    Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version "+oldVersion
                            +" to "+newVersion
                            +", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("drop table if exists "+Constants.TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}




}
```

Edit -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constants.java

```
package com.cookbook.data;

public class Constants {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="datastorage";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME="diaries";
public static final String TITLE_NAME="title";
public static final String CONTENT_NAME="content";
public static final String DATE_NAME="recorddate";
public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
public static final String TABLE_ROW="row_id";

}
```

Edit ------------------------------------------------------------------------- LogCat

```
04-11 12:31:24.379: I/ActivityThread(8459): Pub com.example.classorganizer:     com.example.classorganizer.DiaryContentProvider
04-11 12:31:24.509: V/MyDBhelper onCreate(8459): Creating all the tables
04-11 12:31:24.529: W/dalvikvm(8459): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40018578)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get     provider com.example.classorganizer.DiaryContentProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     getWritableDatabase called recursively
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3561)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3313)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3269)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     getWritableDatabase called recursively
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:101)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     com.cookbook.data.MyDBhelper.insertdiary(MyDBhelper.java:62)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     com.cookbook.data.MyDBhelper.onCreate(MyDBhelper.java:45)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     com.cookbook.data.MyDB.open(MyDB.java:39)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     com.example.classorganizer.DiaryContentProvider.onCreate(DiaryContentProvider.java:36)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:840)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3558)
04-11 12:31:24.539: E/AndroidRuntime(8459):     ... 12 more
```

Edit ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MyDB.class

```
package com.cookbook.data;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyDB {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;
private final MyDBhelper dbhelper;



// Initializes MyDBHelper instance
public MyDB(Context c){

    context = c;
    dbhelper = new MyDBhelper(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null,
                                            Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);

}


// Closes the database connection
public void close()
{
    db.close();

}

// Initializes a SQLiteDatabase instance using MyDBhelper
public void open() throws SQLiteException
{

    try {
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch(SQLiteException ex) {
        Log.v("Open database exception caught", ex.getMessage());
        db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

}

// updates a diary entry (existing row)
    public boolean updateDiaryEntry(String title, long rowId)
    {

        ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
        newValue.put(Constants.TITLE_NAME, title);

        return db.update(Constants.TABLE_NAME, newValue, Constants.KEY_ID + "=" +     rowId, null)>0;

    }

// Reads the diary entries from database, saves them in a Cursor class and returns     it from the method
public Cursor getdiaries()
{
    Cursor c = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, null, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}

}
```

Edit ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
new error logcat

```
04-11 13:26:55.699: I/ActivityThread(9752): Pub com.example.classorganizer:     com.example.classorganizer.DiaryContentProvider
04-11 13:26:55.809: V/MyDBhelper onCreate(9752): Creating all the tables
04-11 13:26:55.839: W/dalvikvm(9752): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40018578)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get     provider com.example.classorganizer.DiaryContentProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     getWritableDatabase called recursively
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3561)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:3313)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3269)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     getWritableDatabase called recursively
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:101)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     com.cookbook.data.MyDBhelper.insertdiary(MyDBhelper.java:64)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     com.cookbook.data.MyDBhelper.onCreate(MyDBhelper.java:47)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:126)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     com.cookbook.data.MyDB.open(MyDB.java:39)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     com.example.classorganizer.DiaryContentProvider.onCreate(DiaryContentProvider.java:36)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:840)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:3558)
04-11 13:26:55.859: E/AndroidRuntime(9752):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: `Drop table <table-name>` or `truncate <table-name>`

Comment: I run this code in MyDBhelper?

Comment: Yes, in a separate method.

Comment: it says drop cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: can you paste that code like here ?

Comment: I updated my code up in here

Comment: you have added `public void drop() {
drop diaries;
}` this code ?

Comment: Your syntax was suppose to be `drop table <table-name>` i.e. `drop table diaries`

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - drop cannot be resolved to a type
 - Syntax error on token "diaries", delete

Comment: do you have table name `diaries` in your db or not ?

Comment: yes I do have this table in db

Answer (score 0):

You can delete your table in following way,

```
public void dropTable() 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL ( "drop table diaries" );
}
```

The above method will delete your table and data too. But if you dont want to delete table and want to delete only records then you can try following method,

```
public void deleteData( String tableName ) 
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL ( "truncate table " + tableName );
    // db.execSQL ( "delete from " + tableName );  Using delete query
}
```

Comment: your code looks all right but it doesn't resove my problem. I wanted to drop table so I can recreate it a new with a for loop to create new rows... New rows are not being created.

Comment: do you want to delete only a single table or whole database ? dropTable() method will surely delete the table.

Comment: I tried to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893385/updating-rows-instead-of-creating-new-entries-database-android/22893778?noredirect=1#comment35077011_22893778

Comment: I run the code with your method but the loop statement to create new rows upon database creation doesn';t kick start

Comment: do you have other table too ?

Comment: no, at this point there is only one table. I updated code with Constants.java

Comment: ok then best solution, delete your application from emulator or device and run the code again. I will be back after lunch

Comment: when you come back can you please have a look at my main issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893385/updating-rows-instead-of-creating-new-entries-database-android

Comment: There, I am unable to utilize a for loop to create 48 rows upon database creation. I put the code in onCreate() method but without any effects.

Comment: First thing first, did you try removing your application ?

Comment: from the device, yes I did.

Comment: then you should be able to add new column to your table now.

Comment: I wanted to create 48 rows in the table as it is being created for further update possibilities.

Comment: And for now no updates are happening. I can insert new row but I cannot edit any row because non have been created by the loop.

Comment: At the moment none. And I don't want to add any apart from the for loop which will create 48 rows. I want to edit them later. For now edit doesn't work because loop didn't create any rows.

Comment: are you trying to say that you are doing updation operation for the rows which you haven't created !!!

Comment: I don't update anything, the function is there to update but I don't use it since I know that rows ae not there. I can insert new rows easily though but thats not the point. I cannot manage to create 48 rows upon database creation and thought that maybe it wasn't possible since the database was already there, but after removing table loop doesn't work neither.

Comment: well after removing the table, you need to create table once again.

Comment: I thought that public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) does it

Comment: that method is to create a database, not table. A table is single entity while database is collection of tables. That's why I suggest you to delete your application so that it will remove your database and when your fresh application gets execute again, that onCreate() method also get called.

Comment: With all respect, I did delete the application and loop within onCreate() didn't kickstart... I don't understand why.

Comment: and now the app crashes after removing it and launching again

Comment: I need to remove the for loop from the code so the app runs.

Comment: well the app starts if there is no loop statement to create rows. But, since my Diary file with edittext fields is meant to update not create, I cannot modify the table. No adding and no creating. I could come back to creating new rows instead the for loop statement but I would not be able to assign the rows to the corresponding time blocks

Comment: are you trying to say that when you are creating a database at that time you are statically inserting few datas ?

Comment: I don't insert any data at this point. Table is empty. I had a for loop statement in onCreate() method to precreate 48 rows for further updates but at the moment there is no loop here and table is empty

Comment: @paddyfox,I got your problem now. Let me write a new answer. just 5 minutes

Comment: You welcome, please check the answer and tell me how it works for you.

Comment: But Eclipse says that getWritableDatabase() is undefined for the type MyDB.

Comment: `MyDB` ?? You have wrote insertDiary() method in `MyDBhelper` class right ?

Comment: and still need to change insertdiary() to static in order to use for loop in MyDBhelper

Comment: ok, no errors now so I'll give it a try with removing app and restarting.

Comment: but in question you have uploaded the code of `MyDBHelper` So I was concentrating on it.

Comment: yes, you are right, I was moving this code from MyDB to MyDBhelper back and forth

Comment: crashes with loop statement and without it runs normally but I have no rows created;/

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     getWritableDatabase called recursively` I thought about it too. Do you have two `SQLiteOpenHelper` files in your project ?

Comment: Sorry for stupic question but how can I verify that?

Comment: That's fine. Do you have `MyDB` & `MyDBHelper` two different class files that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` ?

Comment: If you tell me where to look for it I will tell you straight away. As far as I remember I didn't create file names SQLiteOpenHelper. It is mentioned in the code though.

Comment: MyDBhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper but I don't know anything of such about MyDB

Comment: You said in previous [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005188/how-to-delete-database-and-create-it-a-new-one/23006021?noredirect=1#comment35145284_23006021) that you have `MyDB` class, right. So what does that class do in your project ?

Comment: I posted MyDB file in edited question, hopefully will help you(and me) understand what's going on there

Comment: Hmm, actually you dont need to create two different for this, Now do this add this statement `this.db = db;` before this statement `db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);` in `MyDBhelper` class. Please delete your old application and run fresh one.

Comment: App continues to crash;/

Comment: Did you remove the old app ?

Comment: without the loop statement there are no errors, so I will put this for loop statement back into onCreate() method.

Comment: Ah.. still same error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:     getWritableDatabase called recursively`

Comment: And I have no idea why it has a problem here

Comment: Can you send me copy of your project by email ?

Comment: if it helps, yes I can

Comment: I am not giving you 100% gurantee, but I will try to solve your problem. my email is in my profile. I can not access my email here in office. So I will do it from home on monday evening, not before that.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will pack the project and send it to you. Maybe you will come with some idea in free time.

Comment: although I cannot see your email

Comment: tell me, once you completed sending.

Comment: this is my email, kedarnath.mahadev@gmail.com

Comment: found it:) and I have just sent the file.

Comment: just to let you know I managed to fix the problem with help of other person. I will post corrected code if you want.

Comment: @paddyfox, ok good to hear that your problem is solved. I just come back from weekend.

Comment: Now I have other problem. I am not sure how to populate edittext with data from row in database

Comment: @paddyfox, new problem ---> please ask new question. But first search solution on google, implement and then ask the question with relative code and error log ( if any ).